# Triggering an event inside ReactJs component from outside

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I am using ReactJs to render a list of elements, call it "list-app". I have another mini app that creates an element, let's call it "create-app". Both of them are rendering functional components into different html nodes.

I have two questions for this context:

1. How do I inject the created element into the "list-app"? Please bear in mind that I want the two mini-apps to be separate.
2. How do I trigger the "list-app" from the "create-app"?

While this could have been done by using Class Based components, I don't understand how to use the useRef or useImperativeHandle in functional react components.

I tried saving a set state function to a window function. Is there a better solution?

```
window.refreshChildren = function() {setRefresh(!refresh)};
```

Comment: You need to expand on your question

Comment: I assume you're rendering those mini apps individually using `React.render`? If so, I think your only chance is a globally (on `window` probably) available helper. Maybe something like a message broker, a simple custom event dispatcher or an [Rx subject](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html). This would then act as a mediator between connected mini apps.

Comment: @Yoshi you're right, i render those individually using React.render. I tried creating a global function with window.refreshChildren = function() {setRefresh(!refresh)}; but running the function is not changing the state. Any idea why?

Comment: Seeing only so little code, I can only guess, but it might be scoping problem. But generally I'd suggest creating that helper independent of those mini-apps. Personally I'd try the with a very simple [event dispatcher](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer) implemenation, and having the mini apps subscribe to it.

Comment: @Yoshi After some troubleshooting i discovered that there was some conflict with the name of the component I was using that was preventing the global function to change the state. The name was "Content". As i changed it to something else, it worked. Weird. Thank you for the link to event dispatcher pattern, it's really useful and I'll look into that.